# Cassandra : Timeseries data and secondary indexes

Tags: cassandra

Lets say I have 100 K users spread over 10 K towns/localities.  I am recv time series data for them say every 5 minutes (for each user)
I dont have town as part of the key.

Is it a good practice to create secondary index on town for such case.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10,000 different keys for secondary indices is definitely not an ideal scenario as that would be a pretty high cardinality.  I would recommend reading Richard Low's article on ['The sweet spot for Cassandra secondary indexing'](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=77).   Read performance would probably be less than ideal as an index scan would need to happen on a replica in each partition.

In your case I would suggest denormalizing by creating a separate table called 'users_by_town' that would allow you to search for users by town.

You could always try both cases and use [request tracing](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html) to understand the costs of secondary indexes in this particular scenario.

Comment: I would just add that "probably" should be changed to "definitely". Secondary indexes are bad for most use cases, as they require looking at all your nodes to satisfy the query. If this is an occasional query where latency and availability aren't critical (and you have reasonable cardinality), then indexes can be ok. You don't appear to have such a use case.

Comment: Hello, will the index table store all keys if say for example, my keys are (user,timestamp). Or its intelligent enough to store just the user with start timestamp and endtimestamp (till the user is in one town)

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, the 'users_by_town' table could be an exact copy of 'users' except the primary keys are different (i.e. (town, user) instead of (user)), or it can just be a table that is simply just town and user, and then you can take the results of querying that table to query the primary 'user' table.  I prefer the first strategy if you can afford to the storage costs.